# Animating drop-shadow spread using SVG filter & animated SVG filter performance

Tags: css, animation, svg, filter, dropshadow

I have the following button that animates the `box-shadow` spread property (the semi-transparent outline grows from 0 to say 3px on hover) since there are no obvious alternatives. While `box-shadow` isn't yet GPU accelerated, `filter: drop-shadow()` is, but doesn't support the spread value which is a dealbreaker for this design.

I'm not sure to what degree is the filter property accelerated as [this post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/hardware-accelerated-animations/) from Chrome dev blog isn't overly specific, but since the `filter` CSS property can reference an SVG filter besides the built-in functions, I have 2 questions:

1. How, if at all, are complex SVG filters referenced by id accelerated in major browsers?
2. If it makes sense performance-wise compared to `box-shadow`, how would I best achieve an animated shadow spread as the above described design using SVG filters (eg. imitate `box-shadow` spread as a hard outline)?

edit: I am aware I could fake this effect using an element behind the button and animating scale, but I'd like to explore the filter possibilities present here.

[image: Button]

```css
button {
  appearance: 'none';
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 hsla(360, 80.5%, 55.7%, 0.1);
  transform: scale(5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: box-shadow 180ms ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px hsla(360, 80.5%, 55.7%, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks, updated with a snippet.